# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type view model but requires generic IEnum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, dictionary

Something catastrophic has happened to my application. Every details page has started saying:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'MyBlogger.Models.PostViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model
>   item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyBlogger.Models.Post]'.

It was fine one minute and the next it started doing this, Every single details page is doing it with some variation on the dictionary type.

The pages I was navigating to was `http://localhost:52202/Post/MainDetails/test-upload`, `http://localhost:52202/Post/Details/qwdqwdw` etc etc

The controller action for example for the first link is this:

```
namespace MyBlogger.Controllers
{
    public class PostController : Controller
    {
        private BlogEntities db = new BlogEntities();
        //public Tag tags = new Tag();
        //
        // GET: /Post/
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> postImages = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            var posts = db.Posts.Where(p => p.BlogUserEmail == User.Identity.Name).Include(p => p.BlogUser).Include(p => p.Category);
            foreach (var item in posts)
            {
                byte[] buffer = item.Picture;
                postImages.Add(item.Id, Convert.ToBase64String(buffer));
            }
            ViewBag.Images = postImages;
            return View(posts.ToList());
        }
        //
        // GET: /Post/Details/5
        //[Authorize]
        public ActionResult Details(string urlslug)
        {
            Post post = db.Posts.First(m => m.UrlSlug == urlslug);
            byte[] buffer = post.Picture;
            ViewBag.ImageToShow = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
            if (post == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(post);
        }
        public ActionResult MainDetails(string urlslug)
        {
            Post post = db.Posts.First(m => m.UrlSlug == urlslug);
            List<Post> posts = db.Posts.ToList();

            byte[] buffer = post.Picture;
            ViewBag.ImageToShow = Convert.ToBase64String(post.Picture);

            PostViewModel model = new PostViewModel
            {
                CurrentPost = post,
                Posts = posts
            };

            if (post == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(model.Posts);
        }
```

The PostViewModel is this:

```
namespace MyBlogger.Models
{
    public class PostViewModel
    {
        public Post CurrentPost { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        public Tag CurrentTag { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Tags { get; set; }
        private List<int> _selectedPostTags;
        public List<int> SelectedPostTags
        {
            get
            {
                if (_selectedPostTags == null)
                {
                    _selectedPostTags = CurrentPost.Tags.Select(m => m.Id).ToList();
                }
                return _selectedPostTags;
            }
            set { _selectedPostTags = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

The MainDetails view:

```
@model MyBlogger.Models.PostViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MainDetails";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CurrentPost.Title)</h2>

<header class="intro-header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <div class="post-heading">
                    @*<a href="#">*@
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="@Html.Raw("data:image/jpeg;base64," + ViewBag.ImageToShow)" alt="">

                        <h1>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CurrentPost.ShortDescription)</h1>
                    <p class="text-left">Posted by <a href="#">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CurrentPost.BlogUserEmail)</a> on @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CurrentPost.PostedOn)</p>
                    <p class="text-left">Category <a href="#">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CurrentPost.Category.Name)</a></p>

                    @*</a>*@
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<fieldset>
    <div class="display-field">
        @*@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BlogUserEmail)*@
    </div>

    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.CurrentPost.Description))
    </div>

    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CurrentPost.Modified)
    </div>
</fieldset>
@Html.Partial("SimilarPosts", Model.Posts)
```

Nothing seems wrong with this why has my entire application started giving these errors?

Stack Trace:

```
    [InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MyBlogger.Models.PostViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyBlogger.Models.Post]'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1.SetModel(Object value) +585831
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary dictionary) +371
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`1.SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ConfigurePage(WebPageBase parentPage) +60
   System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass7.<RenderPageCore>b__6(TextWriter writer) +218
   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +10
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +71
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +64
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +246
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +95
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +258
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +295
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +177
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +89
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9658396
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: It wasnt on a line it was a Server Error in '/' Application.

Comment: Any time I click one of my links to see the details of a Post it throws a error like this?

Comment: What happens if you change `return View(model)` to `return View(model.Posts)`

Comment: @Asad its the same except in reverse order for the dictionary type

Comment: I will upload the stack trace

Comment: The error in that stack trace looks different from the error you posted at the top of the post. If that's what you're getting, it's because when you try to pass in your post objects into your partials etc, the post objects are entity framework proxies. You can either disable proxy creation in your context (and lose things like lazy loading), or you can somehow convert the proxies to instances of the actual class before you add them to your `PostViewModel`.

Comment: Hey sorry I put the wrong stack trace in at first but I changed it round.

Comment: Asad I dont understand this wasn't happening earlier? Its just started? The partial has been around for ages with no issues?

Comment: Also not all my details and index pages have partials but yet its doing the same with them?

Comment: My comment was about the stack trace you posted earlier (which you've now removed). The error you're seeing now would happen if there's a view that requires `IEnumerable<Post>`, but is instead getting a `PostViewModel`. Can you try searching for `IEnumerable<Post>` or `IEnumerable<MyBlogger.Models.Post>`?

Comment: Your `MainDetails` method initializes a new instance of `PostViewModel` but then you only return the `Posts` property (which is typeof `IEnumerable<Post>`) to the view  but the view expects `@model PostViewModel` which would throw an exception. You have not shown the view for `Details.cshtml` but assume you have the same problem - the model you pass to the view is not the same as the model you declare in the view.

Comment: Thanks Stephen missed that after @Asad asked me to try it, the below answer was correct aswell I had stupidly put a model in my layout page and forgot all about it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error

[InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MyBlogger.Models.PostViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyBlogger.Models.Post]'.]

means that one of your views (either a regular view, partial view, maybe even your layout) is declaring it's model type to be IEnumerable<MyBlogger.Models.Post> but the data that is being passed to it is a PostViewModel.

I'd look at your layout view or any shared partial views if this just "suddenly stopped working" and it's impacting a lot of pages.